# Android MenuItem programmatically shake text

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer with menuitems that I add programmatically. Upon clicking a floating action button I would like to make all the MenuItems to start shake (as in move via animation).

I have a shake.xml file as defined below.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:duration="150"
        android:fromXDelta="-10%"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="10%"/>
</set>
```

However, I get a null reference when I attempt the animation:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference`

```
menu.findItem(i).getActionView().startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake));
```

`this` is a reference to the view (MainActivity). I've also tried just using `this` or a few other arguments in the `loadAnimation` argument list.

Here is the surrounding method.

```
public void removeListMode(List<SingleList> lists){
    for (SingleList list: lists){
        menu.add(0, list.getInternalListId(), 0, list.getName());
        menu.findItem(list.getInternalListId()).getActionView().startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake));
    }
}
```

I'm adding the MenuItem's programmatically so the layout resource file I don't think matters very much.

Comment: You should add more details, such as the menu resource, and more code on how you're actually calling this - one line doesn't give much Context.

Comment: And what exactly is `null`?

Comment: Ok I added some more info @Advice-Dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to understand what exactly is `null`.

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke method 'startAnimation(Animation)' on a null object reference
```

If you read your exception carefully, you'll notice it says that it's attempting to invoke `startAnimation` on a null reference.

```
getActionView().startAnimation());
```

And if you look at your code, you can see `getActionView()` is the call right before `startAnimation()`. This means your `getActionView()` is returning `null`.

So, now that we understand our `actionView` is `null`, we can try to fix that.

```
public void removeListMode(List<SingleList> lists){
    for (SingleList list: lists){
        menu.add(0, list.getInternalListId(), 0, list.getName());
        menu.findItem(list.getInternalListId()).getActionView().startAnimation(...);
    }
}
```

Personally, I try to refrain from adding menu items programmatically, as if you can inflate them with xml it's generally easier, and faster. But when you're creating menu items, try to look at what you're actually giving the menu.

```
menu.add(0, list.getInternalListId(), 0, list.getName());
```

You're passing only an `id` and a `name` - there is no `icon` or `actionView` defined. This would be the reason the `actionView` is `null`.

Depending on what kind of `actionView` you want, you will need to find the right method for setting it. You could for example do something like this.

```
public void removeListMode(List<SingleList> lists){
    for (SingleList list: lists){
        // menu.add returns the MenuItem that is added.
        MenuItem item = menu.add(0, list.getInternalListId(), 0, list.getName());
        item.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    }
}
```

You -may- not be able to add the animation right away, depends on the method and how exactly it works with menu inflating. But you should be able to figure it out.